# Angular 6+ , How Call Multi Inner Observable Services And Wait For Getting Result Form Inside To Outside Order

Tags: angular, service, observable, angular2-observables, subscribe

I have a component-A.ts file that has a method-A() that calls a method-B() from a service-B() (the method that I tried to made it observable, so I am not sure I did it correct), something like this

FacilityDetailGridComponent.ts

```
updateNursingUnitList(getUpdate: boolean) {

    const recipeObs = this.nursingUnitEditableTableService.updateNursingUnitList(getUpdate, this.projectID, this.facilityID);

    recipeObs.subscribe(
      data => {
        this.nursingUnitList = data;
      }
    );
  }
```

I need to stop at this point to get whole/complete response then continue,

In method-B() from the service-B(), I call method-C() from Service-C() that is Observable as well (And I am sure that it works properly), like this

NursingUnitEditableTableService.ts

```
updateNursingUnitList(getUpdate: boolean, projectID: number, facilityID: number): Observable<any[]> {

    if (getUpdate == true) {

      this.nursingUnitService.getAllUnits(projectID, facilityID).subscribe(
        (data: nursingUnit[]) => {
          return of(data);
        },
        error => {
          if (error.status == 400) {
            this.errorMsg = "Bad Request Error";
            return of(null);
          }
          if (error.status == 404) {
            this.errorMsg = error.error;
           return of(null);
          }
        }
      )
    } else {
      return of(null);
    }    
  }
```

Service-C() and method-c() are something like this,

NursingUnitService.ts

```
  getAllUnits(projectID: number, facilityID: number): Observable<nursingUnit[]> {
    return this.http.get<nursingUnit[]>(this.baseUrl + `api/FacilityProperties/GetAllUnits/${projectID}/${facilityID}`);
  }
```

So, as you can see, I need to modify the middle service (Service-B and Method-B()) to somehow wait for the inner service and method (Service-C and method-C() that it is already observable) to get complete resoponse then,  return of(finalResopne) to the component that called it (component-A, Method-A())

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mergeMap`  operator in *rxjs* to chain the services calls.

Example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  homeworld: Observable<{}>;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.homeworld = this.http.get('/api/people/1').pipe(
      mergeMap(character => this.http.get(character.homeworld))
    );
  }
}
```

This example use [the `mergeMap` also known as `flatMap` to map/iterate over the Observable values](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html).

So in our example when we get the homeworld, we are getting back an Observable inside our character Observable stream. This creates a nested Observable in an Observable.

The mergeMap operator helps us by subscribing and pulling the value out of the inner Observable and passing it back to the parent stream. This condenses our code quite a bit and removes the need for a nested subscription.

It looks something like this ([source](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap)]:

[image: diagram of mergeMap observables]

Comment: Thanks for reply @Ahsan ! you mean I should call both service-B and Service-C with mergeMap feature in Component-A ??? if your answer is yes, I have to tell you, I can not do it and I don't have access to Service-C resource from component-A.
Sorry if I got you on wrong way!

Comment: @Rudolf Olah and Ahsan, let me explain that in my case the middle service is just a cover/repository on the third service to hide its details, so there is not two different service by to different functionality, just for more cleaning and understanding to avoid make the component more complicated, I just created the third service, moved the code over there and call it by middle service, then use the middle service simply in the component. that's it! Thanks again!

Comment: @MoeinMP you can call/use your service that will consume those your other services just like we use httpClient in your own data services.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ahsan!  I will give it try.

Comment: @MoeinMP sure, please comment after you try it.